# Word for a question whose answer depends on each person

Tags: word-request

Can someone please help me with this:

A word you use to describe some question that got a lot of answer dependent on each person.

Comment: I'm afraid it's unclear. Can you give an example sentence that demonstrates how the word would be used?

Answer (score 1):

There are several words you might use depending on what you mean.

> Subjective question

Do you like him?

> Conditional question

If you are married, do you like the state of your marriage?

> Personal question

Do you want to be married?

> Open ended question

What are your views on the institution of marriage?

> Situationally dependent question

Are you married?

Comment: Or *opinion-based* which is used on StackExchange as one reason to close questions. Synonymous with *subjective*.